# Combining MouseOn with CSS Link Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I’m using a combination of icons and text for some links in the sidebar on my website, but I want both the icon and text to change if the mouse hovers over either of them. Using MouseOn and ‘hover’ in my CSS file, I’ve managed to get this to work when the mouse hovers over the icon, but if the mouse only hovers over the text, only the text changes but not the icon as well. Does anybody know a way to do this please? A link to my site and the code I’m currently using are below. Thanks everybody.

http://www.retelevise.com

```
<span class="social-media-sidebar-panel">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/re.televise" target="_external window fa">
<img src="http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/branding/
socialmedia-facebook-1.png"
onmouseover="this.src='http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/
branding/socialmedia-facebook-2.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://www.retelevise.com/wp-content/themes/myownzee/
branding/socialmedia-facebook-1.png'"
class="social-media-sidebar-icons" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook">
<span style="font-size: 0.8em">Facebook</span></a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try moving your onmouseover and onmouseout events to anchor and change the 'this.' to reference the img by ID.

Comment: Sorry Chase, I don't think I understand any of that. My knowledge about this is quite limited you see ...

Comment: it's basically what Fuzz Ball 007 did above in his jfiddle, he bound the the mouse events to the anchors. The catch is you have different images for each panel (he's showing the same image for everything) so you'll have to adjust how they're being shown

Comment: Yeah, realised I didn't quite meet it. In the middle of changing it to different images.

Answer (score 1):

I've made several changes to the way you've done this:

- Moved your styling and javascript to external files
- Used JQuery for animations (simply easier)

This version now makes use of multiple images.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/Kxh58/)**

**HTML:**

```
<span class="sm">
   <a href="#" class="mediaLink">
        <img class="mediaPic" data-hover="http://placehold.it/60/4477ee/ffffff" src="http://placehold.it/60/224499/ffffff"/>
        <div class="mediaText"> Facebook</div>
    </a>
</span>
<span class="sm">
   <a href="#" class="mediaLink">
        <img class="mediaPic" data-hover="http://placehold.it/60/ee9933/ffffff" src="http://placehold.it/60/777777/ffffff"/>
        <div class="mediaText"> Stack Overflow</div>
    </a>
</span>
<span class="sm">
   <a href="#" class="mediaLink">
       <img class="mediaPic" data-hover="http://placehold.it/60/66aaff/ffffff" src="http://placehold.it/60/3388aa/ffffff"/>
        <div class="mediaText"> Twitter</div>
    </a>
</span>
<span class="sm">
   <a href="#" class="mediaLink">
        <img class="mediaPic" data-hover="http://placehold.it/60/dd1122/ffffff" src="http://placehold.it/60/991122/ffffff"/>
        <div class="mediaText"> YouTube</div>
    </a>
</span>
```

**JavaScript (Using JQuery):**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".mediaLink").on( {
        mouseenter: function() {  
            $(this).children(".mediaPic").data("static", $(this).children(".mediaPic").attr("src"));
            $(this).children(".mediaText").css("color", "orange");
            $(this).children(".mediaPic").attr("src", $(this).children(".mediaPic").data("hover"));

        }, mouseleave: function() {

            $(this).children(".mediaText").css("color", "white");
            $(this).children(".mediaPic").attr("src", $(this).children(".mediaPic").data("static"));
        }
    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.mediaLink {
    display: block;
}

.mediaPic {
    float: left;
    width, height: 60px;
}

.mediaText {
    height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: #242424;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Consolas"," Arial";
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
}

.sm {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

### Explanation:

I'm making the `<a>` change its `children` (`.mediaPic` and `.mediaText`) when its being hovered over. On `mouseenter` is when the mouse is hovered over, and `mouseleave` is returning the `<a>` back to its regular state.

The part called `data-hover` is the url of the picture you wish to set the image to, where you leave `src` as the image you want to have as the default. When you hover over the image, the script will "remember" the original `src` and set it back to that when you leave the image (`mouseleave`).

Comment: Thank you. Will give this a go. Really appreciate it.

Comment: As said by Chase Rocker, this will only work for one single image blanketed across all of them - somehow forgot this in my head when I made the solution. I'm working on a multi image solution.

Comment: there are different ways to do it...here's a not so clean way: http://jsfiddle.net/EtPTb/1/ but I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. The standard way of doing it is to use a CSS sprite which has all the images. Each img src would be the same sprite, only the y position would be different, then in the mouseevent, you shift the x to display the correct image.

Comment: This also relies on using a standard naming convention, though yes image sprites would be the way to go

Comment: Thinking about it now, the absolute best method would be to ditch jQuery and go with ::before for each image, means you'd only have to set classes for each image and you could edit the background images via css.

Comment: Thanks everybody. But for some reason I can't get any of the pictures to display. I think it might be to do with the Javascript? Because my site runs entirely on WordPress, I copied the Javascript into the functions.php file but it doesn't like it and the page doesn't display. Sorry to be a pain, but any ideas please? Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the JavaScript file link into either your header.php or into the `<head>` tag on one of your pages. You can see more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript).